# Solr DIH Indexing status of Mails

Tags: email, solr, dih

I am using Solr DIH to index emails from Outlook. The first time I started the indexing process, there were over 5000 emails that had to be indexed. As the indexing progressed there were no updates to any of the status messages.The messages continued to remain as follows: "Total Requests made to DataSource": "0","Total Rows Fetched": "0","Total Documents Processed": "0","Total Documents Skipped": "0".

Initially I thought that the DIH process had hung. But after around 15 minutes, the processing status messages started to show "Total Documents Processed": "1" and so on.

I researched a bit and came to know that Solr DIH reads the email headers first before starting the processing of emails. So probably the first 15 minutes, it was reading the headers.

My question is : Is there any way to get an update on the status of reading email headers? "Total Header Processed : 25" or some such thing?

My dih config is as follows :

```
<entity folders="INBOX" host="imap.mail.yahoo.com" name="Yahoo Mail" 
password="${dataimporter.request.pwd}" processAttachments="true" 
processor="MailEntityProcessor" protocol="imaps" user="myemail@yahoo.com">  
    <field column="messageId" name="id"/>
    <field column="sentDate" name="lastmodified"/>
    <field column="subject" name="title"/>
</entity>
```

Comment: could you share your dih config?

Comment: There's an hidden property in the connectToMailbox method: if there's a [system property set for mail.debug, it's passed on to the imap module](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/98276481e4104d4916a6b0e901d79c6b81f68d30/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/MailEntityProcessor.java#L372). That might give you more feedback about what's happening in the log file. There's extensive debug information logged under the `info` level as well, so be sure to change your solr logging level (can be done under the admin interface and logging)